# One is to many relationship in SQL Server Management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design, relational-database

I don't get it why is it that the relationship in my table is inverted? and how would  I set the Foreign key to auto increment?  so that when I insert a data in my parent table the primary key in my child table will also increment.

And Why is it in my diagram the relationship is inverted, here have a look

[image]

It is supposed to be the other way around, how would I do that?

Comment: Are you related to this question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/9260543/27535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I honestly wouldn't bother trying to make the UI bend to your requirements. Instead, let's learn some DDL!

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.People
(
  PeopleID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  FirstName NVARCHAR(32)
  --, LastName, etc.
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Address
(
  AddressID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  PeopleID INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY 
    REFERENCES dbo.People(PeopleID),
  Address VARCHAR(255)
  --, other columns
);
```

Example of data population. Let's say you want to add a new person named Bob who has two addresses.

```
DECLARE @PeopleID INT;

INSERT dbo.People(FirstName) SELECT N'Bob';

SELECT @PeopleID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT dbo.Address(PeopleID, Address) SELECT @PeopleID, '255 Hemlock Lane';
INSERT dbo.Address(PeopleID, Address) SELECT @PeopleID, '345 Hutcheson Ave';
```

Comment: .I see, btw just a question, if I ever added a data in my primary in the  parent table, will the foreign key in the other table will be updated?

Comment: No, you need to do that yourself, foreign key tables don't get auto-populated. If you added a new person by running an `INSERT dbo.People`, should SQL Server guess the other data that should go in the address table?

Comment: How would I put this, for example. if I added a new data in may parent table, the foreign key in the other table which is related to it will get have the same value as the key referenced to it. or linked to it. am I making myself clear?

Comment: I thought I just demonstrated that with the change to the sample code. If you run that code you will see that when you run the insert into `dbo.People`, you will have a row with `PeopleID = 1`. The next two inserts put new rows in `dbo.Address` - they'll have `AddressID` values of 1 and 2, but will both have `PeopleID = 1`.

Comment: it finally worked, Sorry I didn't see the reply.How did you do that? THe code is working but i have no idea how, care to explain?

Comment: `PeopleID` is an `IDENTITY` column. This means that its value gets auto-populated with an incrementing number. The `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` function returns the last `IDENTITY` value generated in the current scope. So once you've inserted a row and assigned that to a variable, you can insert that value into subsequent tables.

Comment: Is that type of query applicable in LINQ To MYSQL in .NET? and last question. how come when I insert data in SQL management studio, it gives me an error?

Comment: Wow. Ok, I haven't used LINQ to MYSQL. If you're using MYSQL, why is the question tagged as SQL Server? Plus I have no idea why you are getting an error. You need to show the code you're using, the table you created, and the actual error message. But please don't do that in a comment.

Comment: it is tagged in SQL Server since I am making this with SQL Server sorry. okay I'll just post my error on another question. but your answer did answer my question. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look interveted to me.  `People` looks like it has a foreign key referencing `Address`'s primary key.  In which case, no it is supposed to look like that.  That's how the database diagram tool portrays a foreign key relationship.

You wouldn't set your foreign key to auto-increment.  A foreign key is a reference to a primary key in another table.  In other words, it would match a primary key value from the parent table.

Comment: so how would I add a value in my Address_id table so that  I could know if its linked to the address table. and another thing. I want my Address table to be dependent on the Peoples table how would I do that?

Comment: @KyelJmD Your diagram has it the other way around: your Peoples table is dependent (and referencing) your Address table.

Comment: How would I do it the other way around? where Address is dependent in People? and the same time it has a one to many relationship. where one Person can have many address?